# Reading and storing all words of file in prolog

Tags: list, file-io, prolog

I am a newbie to prolog, till now I am able to read all words of file, displayed them one by one, now I want to store them in a list(one by one, as I soon as I am displaying them). All logic for append given everywhere, append content of two lists in an empty list. For example
append(new_word,word_list,word_List), intially my word_list is empty, so everything fine, but afterwards it says no, and stop at that point.
Need help to be able to store element in list one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use difference lists :

```
file_to_list(W, L) :-
   read_word(Word),
   append_dl(W, [Word|U]-U, Ws),
   !, file_to_list(Ws, L).

file_to_list_1(Ws, Ws).


append_dl(X-Y, Y-Z, X-Z).
```

You call **file_to_list(U-U, L-[])** to get the list of words. There is no slowdown but takes more inferences than CapelliC's code (one per word).